# debugging remote websphere application from eclipse

Tags: websphere, remote-debugging, jvm-arguments

I've configured my server to run with the following flags:

**Server--> Server Types --> WebSphere application servers --> Additional Properties --> Debugging Service:**

```
JVM Debug Arguments= -Xdebug -Xnoagent -Xrunjdwp:transport=dt_socket,server=y,suspend=n,address=8888
JVM Port= 8888
```

I configured eclipse debug configuration with the server ip (verified that ip is reachable with the ping command) and port
To be sure i increased the debugger timeout as well .

I've got: `Failed to connect to remote VM. Connection refused.`
Connection refused: connect

so i did a port scan on the server with (nmap xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx -p 8888) and the port seems: 
PORT     STATE  SERVICE
8888/tcp closed sun-answerbook

moreover looking at the section  **Server--> Server Types --> WebSphere application servers --> Communications-->Ports**  of WebSphere admin consolle
i don't see the port 8888 in the list.

what do i need to do?

- open the port on the machine?  (how?)
- add the port in the list of the above mentioned section?
- other?

> @@@@@@ EDITED @@@@@@@@

ADDITIONAL CHECKS

```
netstat -na | grep 8888   --->no listening port/doesn't show me nothing

----------------------------------------------------------------------------

[root@dmgr ~]# iptables -L
Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination

Chain FORWARD (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination

----------------------------------------------------------------------------

C:\Users\alex>nmap 192.168.115.235 -p 8888

Starting Nmap 7.60 ( https://nmap.org ) at 2018-02-23 10:58 ora solare Europa occidentale
Nmap scan report for xxxx.xxxxxxxxxxxx.com (192.168.115.235)
Host is up (0.0018s latency).

PORT     STATE  SERVICE
7777/tcp closed cbt

Nmap done: 1 IP address (1 host up) scanned in 4.59 seconds
```

so, no listening port on 8888, no iptables rules that deny the connection, how to investigate further?

Answer (score 0):

You are almost there :-)
On the `Debugging Service` page where you set the port and arguments, there is a checkbox - `Enable service at server startup` - ensure that it is checked.
If not, **check**, and **restart** the server.

After that you should see the debugging port open. You can check it for example via `netstat -an`.

If the port is open and you still cannot connect then it is probably the firewall issue.

Here some more details about setting the debug - [Starting the application server in debug mode](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSRTLW_9.0.0/com.ibm.debug.wsa.doc/topics/tbwowasd.html)

Comment: i did the checks that you suggested me, but the port seems closed, is it correct? i've added further details to the post

Comment: @alex make sure that you Save changes and Restarted the server (so it has fully stopped correctly and then restarted). Port should be listening just the same as other WAS ports like 9043 9060 9080 9443. So if see other ports but not this, then it looks like it was not correctly save/restarted. You can also for test change the http port for example to 9081 and see if that change is reflected.